# mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'dostin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\...\abrir_conexion.php on line 14

Tags: php, mysql

Este es mi error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el erro de la linea 28, registro.php: Include al quitarlo me deja colocar login y password de los usuarios registrados en la BD, pero si se ingresa la clave de forma errada informa, pero se ingresa de forma correcta no pasa al achivo registro.php donde esta un formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error de la linea 14, abrir_conexion.php:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Revisaste las credenciales credenciales? Pareciera que el error que tienes es en las credenciales que estás colocando para la base de datos. Si en la terminal ejecutas  $ php abrir_conexion.php te da algun error y si te da un error cual

Comment: Hola @Yamid, el código que tienes en la imagen pégalo en tu pregunta. El objetivo es facilitar a los demás copiarlo, probarlo y corregirlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la conexión la puedes hacer con `mysqli_connect( $host, $usuariodb, $clavedb,$basededatos)`

Comment: Las dos formas la del OP y la tuya funcionan igual así que dudo por ahi vaya el error

Comment: Al colocar mysli_connect... ya no genera el error, pero no deja logearse con los usuarios con las claves correctas, tambien me informan que estan erradas.

Comment: Creo que sería mejor que edites la pregunta y coloques el código en lugar de imágenes, creo que el problema puede estar en cerrar_conexion.php colócala también